# How to iterate over nested objects and arrays in meteor / blaze / spacebars

Tags: meteor, spacebars

Okay so I'm new to meteor and have a somewhat complex data structure setup. 
Assuming I'm forced to keep the structure what do my templates need to look like in order to display this? Am I doing something wrong? I can't seem to get my current code to work. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated! -Thanks

Here's my data structure:

```
Tournament: {
    round1:{
        match1:[
            {ToqeLokbLAs9mALd3: {win: true, gamertag: 'gbachik'}},
            {scH8Zb3XMa5ALZNsL: {win: false, gamertag: 'test'}}
        ],
        match2:[
            {c4LQoXGEo6dA8ZtNT: {win: false, gamertag: 'test2'}},
            {TDrZa3QY3AinxXw5D: {win: true, gamertag: 'test3'}}
        ]
    },
    round2:{
        match3: [
            {ToqeLokbLAs9mALd3: {win: true, gamertag: 'gbachik'}},
            {TDrZa3QY3AinxXw5D: {win: false, gamertag: 'test3'}}
        ]
    },
    consolation:{
        match1: [
            {scH8Zb3XMa5ALZNsL: {win: null, gamertag: 'test'}},
            {c4LQoXGEo6dA8ZtNT: {win: null, gamertag: 'test2'}}
        ]
    }
}
```

My Helper:

```
Template.index.helpers({
round: function(){
    return Tournaments.findOne({});
}
});
```

my Route:

```
Router.route('/', function() {
this.subscribe('tournaments').wait();
this.render('index');
});
```

my static view(jade):

```
.tournament
        ul.round1.of3
            li
                .participant.winner
                    a(href='#')
                        span.participant-title= this
                        span.participant-number 2
                .participant
                    a(href='#')
                        span.participant-title asdasd loser
                        span.participant-number 3
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include some information on how you want the tournament data displayed.

Comment: Here's the basic idea [visual](http://cl.ly/image/3G2N0n2Q1724)

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `{{#each}} {{/each}}` spacebars. It should get you at least outputting a list. http://meteorcapture.com/spacebars/.

Just a suggestion for how to format your object, make it much more general. Rather than naming it `round1` and `round2` make a general object that is `round` and then have a `name` or `number` parameter inside the object. If you care about order, consider using a list as the container.